# Evaluate the Integral $\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\tan^4\theta-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Need Help Evaluating the Integral $\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\tan^4\theta-1}$
Think that you use U substitution and then partial fractions, but I keep getting the wrong answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cab you share with us this wrong answer and how you get it?  I am sure someone somewhere on this site did $$\int \frac{dx}{x^4-1}$$

Comment: I think what is really being asked for is what you did in the partial fraction decomposition and subsequent integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cfrac{\sec^2{\theta}}{\tan^4{\theta}-1}$ = $\cfrac{\cos^2{\theta}}{\sin^4{\theta} - \cos^4{\theta}}$ (after multiplication by $\cfrac{\cos^4{\theta}}{\cos^4{\theta}}$)

= $\cfrac{\cos^2{\theta}}{(\sin^2{\theta} + \cos^2{\theta})(\sin^2{\theta} - \cos^2{\theta})}$ = $\cfrac{\cos^2{\theta}}{\sin^2{\theta} - \cos^2{\theta}}$

After applying the trigonometric identities for $\cos{2\theta}$, we get:

$\cfrac{\frac{1}{2}\cos{2\theta} + \frac{1}{2}}{-\cos{2\theta}}$

Does this make things easier?